# Trying to grab all anchor tags except the first 5

Tags: css, web-scraping, css-selectors

Trying to select all anchor tags with `[anchor-tag]` but don't want to grab the first 3 that is all selected. i tried the `:not()` but unable to get it to work. I noticed that the first 3 anchors I DO NOT want to grab is in a div class `.web-container`. I am trying to Inspect Element and do CTRL + F and find the `.web-content a[anchor-tag]` and it shows me 43 and when i do the `:not(.web-container)` addition to it, I get 0. anyway to test it in inspect element and/or get it to show the only ones i want by skipping the first 3 within that css selector list?

I tried the `:not()` and tried different ones but I am not getting the result I need, I find 53 items but only trying to skip the first 3 and grab the next 50 (skipping the first 3)

```
.web-content a[anchor-tag]:not(.web-container)
```

Comment: Please edit your question, do you want "only trying to skip the first 3" or 5 as stated in the title?  See if you can simplify your question to be specific and not quite so rambling in content to make it clear an concise to everyone reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I really haven't seen your Markup, but there is a hight chance that this will solve your issue;

```
.web-content a:nth-of-type(-1n+5) { 
      ---your stylings---
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
.list li:nth-child(n+4){
  background: #C00;
  display: block; 
}
```

Check out this PEN, let me know if this solves your issue:
https://codepen.io/noellastrella/pen/agYKjR